# Tensor product smooth and Isotropic smooth

Tags: regression, smoothing, generalized-additive-model

In 'mgcv', it is possible to fit two or more dimensional thin plate regression splines but not basis like cubic and P-splines. However, with tensor product smooth (te), we can use all the basis. My question is (1) is 1 dimensional te() in R equivalent to 1 dimensional s(,bs="cr/ps,etc") and (2) why we don't simply use te() all the time?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a bit more information on what you are trying to achieve? Some notation and/or code will also be very welcome.